# Nginx 404 on static files (react application)

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, nginx

I tried to setup a React application on nginx, but I faced a problem when serving static files from a subdirectory

My file tree is like this :

```
/var/www/
  antoinedeveyrac.io/
    ...
  react/
    ...
    build/
      index.html
      static/
        js
          *.js
        css
          *.css
```

My conf file is :

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    include snippets/ssl-antoinedeveyrac.io.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    root /var/www/antoinedeveyrac.io/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name antoinedeveyrac.io www.antoinedeveyrac.io;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    location /react {
        alias /var/www/react/build;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        autoindex off;
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

So when I am hitting https://antoinedeveyrac.io/react, I have those 404 errors, which means nginx doesn't understand that I want to serve file from `https://antoinedeveyrac.io/react/static/...` instead of `https://antoinedeveyrac.io/static/...`

How can I fix my config file to match my static files inside a subdirectory ? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score -1):

Are you getting 404's on the assets being referenced in /var/www/react/build/index.html, or on the index.html page itself? I would ask this in a comment, but rep is not high enough yet.

Your nginx root config is pointing to an `html` directory which doesn't appear to exist, based on the directory output you posted.

```
root /var/www/antoinedeveyrac.io/html;
```

Try changing the root config to ...

```
root /var/www/antoinedeveyrac.io/
```

In your index.html, you should reference assets like this(if you are not doing already)

```
<link href="scripts/somefile.css" rel="stylesheet">
```